# AWS looping command to convert hundreds of volumes from GP2 to GP3

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Everyone,

I have a couple of commands that work independently, but when I put them together to loop, they don't work.  Could anyone provide some insights on how to properly parse the volume IDs from the first command so that I can convert all 700+ volumes from GP2 to GP3?

Command 1:

```
aws --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].{Id:VolumeId}' --filters "Name=tag:conversion,Values=true" --output text
```

vol-030eaf37f086cb4c4
vol-07180e1d0599c05a5
vol-088464511be6f2467
vol-09e005a4e19379b5c

Command 2:

```
aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-type gp3 --volume-id vol-xxxxxxxxxxxx --region us-east-1
```

So, I used the following:

```
for i in $(aws --region us-west-2 ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].{Id:VolumeId}' --filters "Name=tag:conversion,Values=true" --output text); do echo "Converting Volumes" $i; aws ec2 modify-volume --query 'Volumes[*]' --volume-type gp3 --region us-west-2 $i; sleep 1; done;
```

But does not work.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

CL

Comment: "But does not work." is not very specific. Why exactly it does not work? Any error messages?

Comment: There are several differences between your command 2 and the command you use in the body of your for loop. Additionally, you should quote `$i` like `"$i"` to prevent word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Excel**

Frankly, I sometimes use Excel to run a large number of commands:

- First, obtain the list of Volume IDs from the first command, preferably with each ID on a separate line (use `--query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]' --output text`)
- Put them in the first column in Excel, then make a formula in the second column that refers to the first column:

```
="aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-type gp3 --volume-id "&A1
```

- Then, **Fill Down** for all the rows
- You can then Copy & Paste the commands into a Terminal window (test with a couple first, before running them all)

**Using Python**

Alternatively, you could **script it in Python**. It would be something like this (but I didn't test it):

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

response = ec2_client.describe_volumes(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:conversion', 'Values': ['true']}])

for volume in response['Volumes']:
    ec2_client.modify_volume(VolumeId=volume['VolumeId'], VolumeType='gp3')
```

Comment: John,

I appreciate the feedback -- I will attempt both options, but it seems to me either one will work to achieve the desired result.   Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

**Using bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find all gp2 volumes within the given region
volume_ids=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filters Name=volume-type,Values=gp2 | jq -r '.Volumes[].VolumeId')

# Iterate all gp2 volumes and change its type to gp3
for volume_id in $volume_ids;
    do
    aws ec2 modify-volume  --volume-type=gp3 --volume-id "$volume_id" | jq '.VolumeModification.ModificationState' | sed 's/"//g'
    echo "Good  changement" > gp2.txt
done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).